# js submit not works not sending post form data to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

After certain time (2min) when i try form submit using javascript it just submit form without post data value !!! searched solution on web but unable to find solution!! Hope someone can help me

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

          $('.countdown.callback').countdown({
          date: +(new Date) + 120000,
          render: function(data) {
            $(this.el).text( this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + "min " + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " sec");
            if(this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) < 01 && this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) <=  10){
                 $(this.el).addClass('ended');
                }
          },
          onEnd: function() {

              document.getElementById('myform').submit();


          }
        });

       });

</script>
```

html code with php

```
<?php 
   foreach($row as $r){

       if(!empty($r['question'])){

?>    
 <form   method="post" id="myform" action="subanswer.php" >

<p><span style="color:rgb(33,79,157);"><?php echo  $r['id'];?> <?php echo  $r['question'];?></span><br />

<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $r['test_id'].'_'.$r['id'];?>"  value="<?php echo $r['ans1'];?>">  <?php echo $r['ans1'];?>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $r['test_id'].'_'.$r['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $r['ans2'];?>">  <?php echo $r['ans2'];?>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $r['test_id'].'_'.$r['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $r['ans3'];?>">   <?php echo $r['ans3'];?>

<input type="hidden" name="testname" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">

</p>
<?php
       }
       }
?>


  <input type="submit" name="subans" value="add"  class="but" style="width:15%;" />

</form>
```

Comment: Hope you can post your code

Comment: Where is your code? What you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: when 2min ends onend function it submits to subanswer.php but it does not submit any post values to php script it just submits with no values !!!

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like you're calling the wrong form:

`document.getElementById('myForm').submit();`

The ID `myFom` does not exist. You have:

`<form   method="post" id="myform1" action="subanswer.php" >`

Also not sure why people don't stick to JQuery throughout. Would advise:

`$("#myForm1").submit();`

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? I would advise adding some `console.log()` in different parts so you can watch the progression of your script and it's execution.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function , Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function on javascript console

Comment: This suggests that JQuery is not loaded. Ensure that JQuery is loading and check your Console.

Comment: you are right i am using bootstrap not js not loaded properly will check it and let you know thanks